# Do Windows containers share resources like Linux containers?

Tags: windows, docker

Containers on Linux share the OS kernel and thus processor cores, memory, disk space, etc.

On Windows, as far as I know, there are two types of containers: Linux containers via WSL2 and Windows containers. WSL2 runs in a VM, so probably does not share with the rest of the Windows world, but within the other Linux containers.

With Windows Container, I have no idea at all how this technique works. Is the Windows kernel also shared here? Are processor cores, memory, disk space and so on shared among the containers, so that the resources can be used as best as possible like on Linux? Or does each container get a fixed amount of RAM, for example, as in a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows containers *can* share resources, yes.

Windows containers offer two distinct modes of runtime isolation: process and Hyper-V isolation. Containers running under both isolation modes are created, managed, and function identically. They also produce and consume the same container images. The difference between the isolation modes is to what degree of isolation is created between the container, the host operating system, and all of the other containers running on that host.

*Process Isolation* is the "traditional" isolation mode for containers and is what is described in the Windows containers overview. With process isolation, multiple container instances run concurrently on a given host with isolation provided through namespace, resource control, and other process isolation technologies. When running in this mode, containers share the same kernel with the host as well as each other. This is approximately the same as how Linux containers run.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container

Comment: Nice direct copy/pasta from Microsoft entry page documentation. Must have been hard work.

Answer (score 1):

So answer is yes,

Please refer this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/resource-controls

Comment: Nice article, will keep it in my bookmarks.